# How to hide popover when modal open

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, popover, bootstrap-popover

Let's say I have a popover that contains `links` `<a>` and some of these links can open `modal`.

The problem is that this popover is still active when modal is open.
How to  hide all active popovers when any modal show **after clicking on those links inside this popover?**

```
<div class="popover-content">
<ul class="popover-ul">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-msg="<h4>OUT</h4><img src='yourlinkhere' alt='OUT'>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#doc-modal" data-ok="data-ok">
      OUT
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use popover hide function to hide the popover.

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/qy9Az/3414/

```
$('.test').popover('hide')
```

**in your Case i think this will help**

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover('hide')
});
```

Where test is the class of the element on which popover is attached

See https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#popoverhide for more details

Comment: thanks for your answer
i hope you approve the edit made to be appropriate with the question !

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover('hide')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive i undertand your question set not-visible: **hide popovers**(any), a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tz5oLgLc/)

```
var _pops = document.getElementsByClassName("popover-content");
console.log(_pops)
for(var i=0; i<_pops.length;i++){
_pops[i].style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

Comment: my problem is when i press any link inside the same popover it will show a modal and this popover still active 
i need this popover to be hidden when pressing  link inside it